# Transparent Bitmap on TGraphicControl component

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I created a component based on TGraphicControl.
it is transparent when i draw line directly into its canvas. But when i try to draw a bitmap on its canvas, it is not shown as transparent.
How can i draw a transparent Bitmap on TGraphicControls canvas?
thanks

```
unit Test;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,Types,DB;

type
  TTest = class(TgraphicControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    BMP:TBitmap;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    Procedure Paint; Override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Constructor create(Aoner: Tcomponent); Override;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Automation', [TTest]);
end;

Constructor TTest.create(Aoner: TComponent);
begin
  Inherited Create(Aoner);
  Width:=100;
  Height:=100;
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  BMp.Width:=50;
  BMP.Height:=50;
  BMP.Transparent:=true;
  BMP.TransparentColor:=BMp.Canvas.Pixels[0,0];
  BMP.Canvas.MoveTo(1,1);
  BMP.Canvas.LineTo(50,50);
End;

Procedure TTest.Paint;
Begin
  Inherited Paint;
  Canvas.MoveTo(0,0);
  Canvas.LineTo(100,100);
  Canvas.Draw(0,0,BMp);
End;

Destructor TTest.Destroy;
begin
  Inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: Just add `Bmp.Canvas.Handle;` after creating the bitmap, before setting its size. If you want it to resolve by seemingly making some sense instead, follow the answer and instead of `Bmp.Canvas.Handle;` put something like `Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;`.

Comment: You should make this an answer.  Calling BMP.Canvas.Handle does indeed solve the problem.  Make it an answer, with a short explanation why it works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment .

Comment: @David - Sorry, I cannot. I assume what matters is to have the brush created before setting the size but even after tracing graphics.pas I don't have any explanation about why...

Answer (score 0):

When you create the bitmap, by default, all the pixels are set to a specific value.  In my tests, the value was $FFFFFFFF.  When you call Pixel[0,0], it reads the color at that position, and converts it to RGB.  In this case, $FFFFFF.  So that's your TransparentColor. When the bitmap is rendered, it compares each pixel value to the TransparentColor. Those that match are transparent.  But $FFFFFFFF does not match $FFFFFF, and so those pixels are not transparent.

To get the pixels to be transparent, explicitly set them to be the color you want.